Is there a qiskit method to obtain the generator (ie. Pauli operator) of a gate?
Is there a (qiskit) method to give the generator $H$ in terms of Paulis of some gate $U=e^{iH}$ defined in qiskit. For example, it would take CNOT as input and give a representation of $\pi /4 (I_1 - Z_1)(I_2 - X_2)$ as output. Somewhat the 'inverse' of PauliEvolutionGate that can be used to define a gate $U(t)=e^{-iHt}$ via the Pauli terms $H$.

In general, multiple Hamiltonians can generate the same unitary.
A simple way to get a Hamiltonian is to take the logarithm of the unitary matrix using scipy.linalg.logm then use SparsePauliOp.from_operator to get the Pauli basis representation
from qiskit.circuit.library import CXGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from scipy.linalg import logm

op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(-1j * logm(CXGate().to_matrix()))
print(op)

